# Join Table in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table A with columns a , b, c, d, e and I have  table B with columns m, n, o, p and e. Column 'e' is the same (related) in both tables. Also table A, has about 2,000,000 rows (lookup-table) while table B has about 50,000 rows. Please what I want to do is combine the two tables based on column 'e' in Access and keep only rows that have the same values in column 'e'. I cannot use excel because Table A is to large to open in excel. Thank you

Comment: `join` both table on column `e`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.e = B.e` ... and maybe add an index on `B.e` for performance.

Comment: You are running very close MS Access limits, consider another database if you are using Jet/ACE.